# Any reason to define a header-guard to 1?

Tags: c, header, compatibility, include-guards

Occasionally I observe such header guards:

```
 #ifndef FOO
 #define FOO 1
 ...
 #endif // FOO
```

But I learned it this way:

```
 #ifndef FOO
 #define FOO
 ...
 #endif // FOO
```

Is the define to `1` an old relict to some compiler?, does it do any harm nowadays? What is the way to do it now?

Comment: `#define FOO 1` just permit you to use FOO as 1, it won't do any harm on you compiler. Use it as an include guard is just an old trick to avoid multiple declaration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some include guards have a defined value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323880/why-do-some-include-guards-have-a-defined-value)

Comment: At least to put the "empty" define on the table, it gives some more context why such stmts might exist. We can close this question if you like, and mark it as duplicate, or what ever.