# Why do some include guards have a defined value?

Tags: include, include-guards

Usually when using include guards I write them like so:

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H

...

#endif // FILENAME_H
```

Now in some librarys I've seen something like:

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H 1

...

#endif // FILENAME_H
```

After some reserach I didn't find any reason as to why the include-gurad would be needed to be initialized.

Is there any reason for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I've never seen such a compiler, I've been told an "empty" define could be regarded as not defined.
I'm very interested in which compiler behaves like so.

Even C89 states:
3.8.1 Conditional inclusion
Constraints

The expression that controls conditional inclusion shall be an integral constant expression [...] of the form

defined identifier

defined ( identifier )

which evaluate to 1 if the identifier is currently defined as a macro name (that is, if it is predefined or if it has been the subject of a #define preprocessing directive without an intervening #undef directive with the same subject identifier), 0 if it is not.

Comment: Sadly I don't remember where I saw that, it was probably some library for mathematical functions. It was under linux though.