# Should header guards be defined to something?

Tags: c++, c, header

Are there any (dis)advantages to write

```
#ifndef BLA_H
#define BLA_H 1
```

instead of

```
#ifndef BLA_H
#define BLA_H
```

This was asked before but never answered: [Any reason to define a header-guard to 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541456/any-reason-to-define-a-header-guard-to-1)

Comment: The comment in the linked question is answering it

Comment: Only if something else is using it.  e.g. `#if BLA_H == 1`.

Comment: @273K The answer is actually is linked in the link, which is too difficult to follow. ;-)

Comment: Just use `#pragma once`

Comment: @PepijnKramer I prefer that too, but it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: I know it is not an answer, just a comment ... that's why it is in the comment section ;)
And no there is no advantage unless you do other things with the #define beside using it as a guard (which I would not recommend).  Single responsibility principle ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer -- with the caution that `#pragma once` is not Standard C++ and cannot be implemented correctly in some environments (for example, source code on network drives; there can be different mappings to the same file, and the compiler cannot know that two files on different paths are the same file)

Comment: I prefer to avoid implementation-specific features, which includes all `pragma`s except a handful defined by the language spec.  `#pragma once` is a hard "no" for me.

Comment: @PeteBecker Good addition, but AFAIK : clang,gcc and msvc all support it;

Comment: @PepijnKramer   They may support it.  But, as Pete mentioned, there are circumstances (like source code on network drives, and multiple symbolic links that ostensibly refer to the same file) where `#pragma once` doesn't work - and give the exact problem (such as the compiler seeing multiple definitions of a `struct` type) with those compilers that `#pragma once` is intended to avoid.    The programmer workaround in those cases?   Include guards!

Comment: @Peter And that is good for me to know too, because I never really experienced issues with that (I guess because the build systems I've used past 30 years) never used drive mappings.  So nice case of "Hyrum's law" for me... I never experienced issues so I never looked it up and got to depend on it being right all the time ;)